# How can I regenerate health?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When Shepard's shield collapses, she takes damage to her five health bars.

[image]

I noticed that while partial damage to a health bar regenerates quickly, the health bars themselves don't regenerate. The health you lost stays lost until the end of the mission.

Is there any way to regenerate that health during a mission?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to use medi-gel (which heals your entire squad) to recover bars that have been fully depleted. It can be accessed on your Power Wheel.